# MATLAB: Apply input vector to a vector of functions

Tags: matlab, function, vector

Say I have the following definitions:

```
syms x y z
F = [x^2+y^2+z^2-1; 2*x^2+y^2-4*z; 3*x^2-4*y+z^2];
v = [x, y, z];
```

I want to evaluate F(x=1, y=2, z=3), meaning apply the stored functions to the input.

Alternatively, I could use function handlers for every member of F, but then I couldn't easily calculate the jacobian:

```
J = jacobian(F, v)
```

How can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To evaluate F for some specific values you can use

```
subs(F,{x y z},{1 2 3})
```